# jQuery when() is not working for multiple ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a `JavaScript` method where we have to invoke multiple `ajax` calls and use that data when all available. We have used `jQuery`.when for this situation. But the data received using `jQuery` when method is different from when it is executed separately (just the `ajax` call).

Below is the method call and data received.

Whenever I call same `ajax` method, data has all the elements but when I call it using when method it is wrapped within an array. Could you please let me know what is missing or how to extract the data.

```
  function retailerProfile(){
    $("#retailerProfileBody").empty();
    $('#retailerProfile').modal('show');


    $.when($.ajax({
                url: 'products/getAllProductsByCategory.json',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: {


                },
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
               }
               }), 
               $.ajax({
                   url: 'useroperation/findRetailerByUserName.json',
                   dataType: "json",
                   type: "POST",
                   data: {


                   },
                   beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                       xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                       xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


          }
                })).done(function( products,data){
                console.log( "user :"+data.user);
                console.log( "data :"+data);
    console.log( "products :"+products);
    var profile = '<div id="'+data.id +'">'
                +'<div class="well well-sm">'
                +'<div class="row">'
                +'<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6"><h4>'+data.user.firstName+' '+data.user.lastName+'</h4>'
                +'<address>'
          +'<strong>'+data.shopName+'</strong><br/>'
          +data.address.addrLine1+'<br/>'
          +data.address.addrLine2+'<br/>'
          +data.address.city+'<br/>'
          +data.address.state+'<br/>'
          +'<abbr title="Phone">P:</abbr> '+((!data.user.mobile)?'':data.user.mobile)
                +'</address>'
                +'<p>'
                +'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> '+data.user.email
                +'<br/><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i> '+data.address.locality
                +'</p>'
                +'</div>';
                profile+='<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-6"><h4>Products</h4><br/>'
                +'<ul class="list-group">';
                $.each(data.products,function(k,product){
                profile+='<li class="list-group-item">'+ product.productName +'('+product.category +')</li>';
                });
                profile+='</ul>'
                +'</div>'
                +'</div>'
                 +'</div>'
           +'</div>'
           ;


        $("#retailerProfileBody").append(profile);
    });


    }
```

> Console Log: data :[object Object],success,[object Object] products
>   :[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object
>   Object],success,[object Object]

[image]

Comment: The ajax calls or the results itself are not beeing touched by the when-method. The resulsts should not differ when you use the **exact same** query. You might want to check if your queries differ from another.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is because of when function behavior. in when function each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ].